# Timeout errors when making requests to a third-party API from a specific AWS region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Timeout error when making the request from a specific ec2 region.

I have an Laravel application (using elastic beanstalk) running in the us-east-2 region. When making requests to a specific third-party API from this region, inconsistencies occur.

The first requests take a while but there is a return. However, after some requests ( something like 5 ) I have no more responses and i get ( timeout error ).

At first I thought it was an error in this API. However, making infinite requests from my localhost no error occurs. So I thought of uploading an application identical to the one I have on us-east-2 in another region.
Requests from the new application have no errors. All requests have returns and no get timeout error.

I created the same application again in the us-east-2 region and, again, most of the requests do not return.

I already checked the Inbound/outbound rules, security groups, etc. And, even with the applications having the same rules, the responses is different depending on the region.

PS: When I ping from the server, there is no packet loss, all packets are returned quickly.
PS: I'm having problems with only two api's, there are several others running normally. Upon contacting those responsibles, I discovered that both run using the same hosting service.

I tried to change inbound/outbound rules, create new ec2 serves, change CURl to GuzzleHttp, change the region of instances ( and it works )

Comment: Sounds like it might be one of those networking issues related DNS resolution or routing. Was the new EC2 instance that works not an EB manged instance?

Comment: @Janaka all are manged EB instances.  Have anything to do about that issues? Can you give more specific informations to help me learn about that?

Comment: DNS - the lookup servers that region might have stale records for example if the provider has a DNS config issue or makes a record change that hasn't yet fully propagated. AWS DNS lookup infra might be having an issue. Generally one would try do a nslookup or dig of the API hostname on the machine.

IP routing - us-east-2 might have issues routing to that IPs the API is hosted on. Again could be a route change not propagated fully, a misconfig on an internet router. If the API is also hosted on a AWS, Azure etc this is less likely the issue.